# is there any way to let the user choose which variable is to be inputted?

Tags: c++, user-input

this is for a personal use application in c++
for example:

```
class x                
{...};
int main()
{

string userinput;

cin>>userinput;

cin>>x."userinput";}
```

is something like this possible?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly. You need to overload `operator>>` for `class x`.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly:No such thing isn't possible, since c++ doesn't have any runtime reflection facilities.

Comment: It could be with a hashtable. Instead of variables you just use hash-indexes

Comment: @Matt So you fully understood what the OP wants to achieve here?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i wanted to let the user input a predefined variable that they themselves specify that is they know the predefined variable names beforehand but can choose the one they want to input sorry for not being able to explain my problem correctly

Comment: thanks @πάνταῥεῖ i'll look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are talking about is allowing for the user to set variable names at runtime, then no. It is not possible in c++. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, there are a few ways around this.

If you just need the user to be able to access a small number of variables, all of which are known before hand, you can use a `switch` statement, or a bunch of `if/elseif`s

If you need to store a larger amount of variables the number of which may not be known at compile time, then there exists a number of data structures that exist just for this purpose. There are arrays, hash tables, linked lists and hundreds of variations on the above. These are all far too complex topics to cover in a single answer however.

Comment: No i do want to set variable name at runtime I want to input a particular variable at runtime which is selected by me. Using a switch case/if-else was something i considered but i though there might be a better solution so i asked here. I'll look into hashed tables and try to implement that. Thanks for the help!